# Does a Jamaican living in the UK need a visa to travel to Austria?

Tags: schengen-visas, austria, uk-residents, jamaican-citizens

I live in the UK and have a biometric residence permit after entering on a spouse visa. My nationality is Jamaican.

Comment: What is *I have biametric from my spouse visa*? Why do you think that makes a difference, does your spouse travel with you? What is the intention of your visit (tourism, business)? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 3):

Austria is in the Schengen area, and nationals of Jamaica do need a visa to enter the Schengen area.

Comment: And having a visa or status in the UK does not make a difference.